# How to remove oldest folder(s) of a group of folders in a folder with several folder groups?

Tags: batch-file

The folder `D:\Backup` contains following subfolders listed here with name (left) and last modification date (right) as displayed in Windows Explorer:

```
20171113.224424         15.11.2017 17:24
20171113.224421         16.11.2017 15:26
20171113.224412         16.11.2017 15:33
20171112.424424         16.11.2017 15:33
20171112.224424         16.11.2017 15:33
20171112.221424         16.11.2017 15:34
20171111.224428         16.11.2017 15:34
20171111.224427         16.11.2017 15:35
20171111.224424         16.11.2017 15:34
```

I need a batch script to check if there are more than two folders with same date string with always 8 digits left to `.` in folder name like  `20171113.224424`, `20171113.224421` and `20171113.224412`.

The batch file should keep the newest two folders with same date string and delete all other older folders with using the folder creation date instead of last modification date.

For the example above with creation date being equal the last modification date the folders to delete are:

```
20171113.224424
20171112.224424
20171111.224424
```

When two folders have the same creation date, the one with lower number after the dot should be deleted if that is possible.

The remaining folders are:

```
20171113.224421
20171113.224412
20171112.424424
20171112.221424
20171111.224428
20171111.224427
```

I tried a lot of codes, but I don't post them all here.

I have code which list all folders in directory, but can't find the method to group the folders with same first 8 letters:

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
for /d %%i in (d:\backup\*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    echo current directory:
    cd
    pause
)
cd %back%
```

I wrote code to skip last 10 lines if there a regular grouping and delete the folders that I don't need as described above:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=10 delims=" %%I in ('dir "d:\backup\*" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "d:\backup\%%I"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file for this task would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BackupFolder=D:\backup"
set "LastDate="
for /F "delims=." %%I in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\????????.*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    if not "!LastDate!" == "%%I" (
        for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%D in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\%%I.*" /AD /B /O-D-N /TC') do rd /Q /S "%BackupFolder%\%%D"
        set "LastDate=%%I"
    )
)
endlocal
```

The first, outer **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd /c` in background the **DIR** command line specified in first parenthesis and captures everything output by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** for processing it later line by line.

The used **DIR** command outputs

- only directories matching wildcard pattern `????????.*` because of `/AD` (attribute directory)
- with only their names without path because of `/B` (bare format)
- sorted by name because of `/ON` (ordered by name).

It is possible that the backup folder currently contains no folder matching this pattern. In this case **DIR** would output an error message to handle **STDERR** which would be confusing because of containing *file* instead of *directory*. This possible error message is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the **DIR** command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Outer **FOR** processes the captured lines with ignoring empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon. Such lines do not exist here, so no problem. Each (other) line is split up into two strings using `.` as delimiter. Only the first string left to first `.` of each line is assigned to loop variable `I` which is used in the command lines executed next.

It is important here to use command **DIR** to get a directory list processed by **FOR** not being modified during loop execution instead of using `for /D` which would read next directory name directly from file system on each iteration of the loop. The list of directories changes during loop execution. On using `for /D` it could happen that some directories are skipped because of directory list changes while processing the directories.

The **IF** condition makes a simple case-sensitive string comparison using delayed environment variable expansion to compare the date string of previous processed folder(s) with the current folder. Only on difference between date of last processed folder(s) and date of current folder the inner loop is executed. This **IF** condition is just for making the folder deletion process a little bit faster.

It is no problem here to use delayed environment environment variable expansion as no folder in backup folder contains an exclamation mark in folder name.

The second, inner **FOR** loop runs also command **DIR** to get a list of directories with the date string of current folder with just their names, but this time first reverse ordered by creation date and second reverse ordered by name in case of two or more folders have same creation date because of `/O-D-N` (ordered reverse by date and next reverse by name) and `/TC` (time: creation). Reverse date order means newest directory is output first and oldest is output last.

The inner **FOR** loop processes the captured lines output by **DIR** with skipping the first two lines which means ignoring the two newest folders. The other lines are processed without splitting the line up because of `delims=` (empty delimiter list) and therefore the complete folder name as output by **DIR** is assigned to loop variable `D`.

The command **RD** deletes the folder of which name is hold in loop variable `D` quietly because of `/Q` with all files and subfolders because of `/S`.

Then the date string of current folder is assigned to environment variable `LastDate` to skip all folders in directory list of outer **FOR** with same date string.

It would be also possible to use a single command line without usage of delayed environment variable expansion being a bit slower which would also work for folders with `!` in name.

```
@for /F "delims=." %%I in ('dir "D:\backup\????????.*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do @for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%D in ('dir "D:\backup\%%I.*" /AD /B /O-D-N /TC') do @rd /Q /S "D:\backup\%%D"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

---

**Update:**

Enhanced version logging the names of all files with full path before deletion of a backup directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BackupFolder=D:\backup"
set "LastDate="
set "LogFile=%BackupFolder%\DeletedFiles.log"
for /F "delims=." %%I in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\????????.*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    if not "!LastDate!" == "%%I" (
        for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%D in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\%%I.*" /AD /B /O-D-N /TC') do (
            dir "%BackupFolder%\%%D" /A-D /B /ON /S >>"%LogFile%" 2>nul
            rd /Q /S "%BackupFolder%\%%D"
        )
        set "LastDate=%%I"
    )
)
endlocal
```

Single command line version:

```
@for /F "delims=." %%I in ('dir "D:\backup\????????.*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do @for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%D in ('dir "D:\backup\%%I.*" /AD /B /O-D-N /TC') do @dir "D:\backup\%%D" /A-D /B /ON /S >>"D:\backup\DeletedFiles.log" 2>nul & rd /Q /S "D:\backup\%%D"
```