# How can I create a log file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to save a log .txt file of all deleted files with this code?

Also I need to change code to search for all backup folders in root directory subfolders.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BackupFolder=D:\backup"
set "LastDate="
for /F "delims=." %%I in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\????????.*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    if not "!LastDate!" == "%%I" (
        for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%D in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\%%I.*" /AD /B /O-D-N /TC') do rd /Q /S "%BackupFolder%\%%D"
        set "LastDate=%%I"
    )
)
endlocal
```

This code was written by [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) and posted as answer on [How to remove oldest folder(s) of a group of folders in a folder with several folder groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350040/3074564) He posted also an enhanced version logging the files before deletion, but it was not working for me properly.

I tried with the followed command >> but log.txt file has not been generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attempt to use `>>` was not shown in the question. How about something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BackupFolder=D:\backup"
set "LastDate="
SET "LOGFILE=%TEMP%\%~n0.log"
for /F "delims=." %%I in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\????????.*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    if not "!LastDate!" == "%%I" (
        for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%D in ('dir "%BackupFolder%\%%I.*" /AD /B /O-D-N /TC') do (
            DIR /S /B "%BackupFolder%\%%D" >>"%LOGFILE%"
            rd /Q /S "%BackupFolder%\%%D"
            set "LastDate=%%I"
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: thanks a lot again. this code is right its work also like the code from mofi. the diffrence is that this code is more costumable for my needs i do some combination. i do wrong with code from mofi becouse i tested with empty folders and did not get any results. i need to reconfigure to show any folder deleted. thanks a lot guys you helped me a lot.

Comment: @sn00p Well, if you ask to log the deleted __files__ then you should not really wonder why I wrote the batch code for recording into the log file the __files__ being deleted on next command line. I have even named the log file `DeletedFiles.log`. If you would have asked to log the __directories/folders__ being deleted (just the deleted folders or all folders recursive), I would have written the code to log the deleted folders. For the future be careful on what you are asking for.